# group action on vector spaces V: decomposition of V with characters.

Tags: finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-actions, characters

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group that operates linear on the $\mathbb{C}-$vector space $V$ by 
\begin{equation}
V \times F \longrightarrow V, \quad
(f, a) \longmapsto f^a.
\end{equation}

Then we define
$f^\chi := \{ f \in V \mid f^a = \chi(a) f \} $. Then
\begin{equation}
V = \bigoplus_{\chi} V^\chi,
\end{equation}
where $\chi$ runs through all characters from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$.
I managed to proove the existence of such a decomposition, by
prooving
\begin{equation}
f = \frac{1}{\vert G \vert} \sum_\chi \sum_{a \in G} \chi(a)^{-1} f^a,
\end{equation}
 but didn't manage to proof the uniqueness of it.   We should use somehow
\begin{equation}
\sum_\chi \chi(a) = 
\begin{cases}
0, &for \quad a\neq 0 \\
\vert G \vert  &for \quad a = e_G,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

but I can't find the answer, yet. Does anyone know how to progress?

Comment: Your 1st line is supposed to refer to [$\mathbb{C}[G]$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_finite_groups#Representations.2C_modules_and_the_convolution_algebra) ?

Comment: For irreducible characters of finite abelian groups $\chi(a^{-1}) \chi(x) = \chi(a^{-1}x)$ so that $|G| \delta_a(x) = \sum_\chi \chi(a^{-1})\chi( x)=\sum_\chi \chi(a^{-1} x)$ and hence $|G| f(x) = \sum_\chi \sum_a f(a) \chi(a^{-1}) \chi(x)$